# Want an integer, getting tuples?

Tags: python, nltk

I'm trying to use a simple value system (very ultra simplistic and not expecting wonderful results) to gauge "sentiment" on a document.

I built a for loop using a defaultdict(int) but I'm kind of just flailing my arms around in code and it popped up with tuples instead of an integer, giving value to every word it found rather than summarizing by line as I expected. (I am VERY new to all of this and quite lost. Please don't hate me?)

```
positive = ['accurate','adore','agree','amazed','amazingly','amazing','award worthy',  'awesome','beautiful', 'better','breathtaking','cool', 'enjoy','excited', 'exciting','fantastic',  'friend','glad','good','handpicked', 'handsome', 'happy','hopeful','impressive','improved', 'incredible','like', 'love', 'relieved','right']
negative = ['angry','annoyed','annoying','awful','badly', 'bad','butcher', 'careless','disagree', 'disappointed','disgusting','dislike', 'gross','hated', 'hate', 'horrible','horribly','mutilated','ruin', 'sad','terrible', 'terribly', 'thoughtless','ugh','ugly','unrealistic','worse','worst','wrong']
shifters = ['but','don’t', 'however', 'not']
intensifiers = ['awfully','completely','incredibly', 'majorly','really','seriously','so','wow']


def value_eval(doc):
    value = defaultdict(int)
    for line in doc:
        for word in line:
            if word in positive:
                value[line[0]] += 1
            if word in negative:
                value[line[0]] - 1
            if word in intensifiers:
                value[line[0]] * 1.25
            if word in shifters:
                value[line[0]] * -1.25
    return value
```

I was hoping for an added value of all lines, but wound up with something along the lines of:

```
defaultdict(int,
            {'I': 75,
             ';': 179,
             'But': 13,
             'With': 0,
             'Tolkien': 3,
             'And': 9,
             'even': 1,
             'no': 0,
             '“': 1,
             'You': 5,
             'They': 9,
             'Sure': 5,
             'it': 7,
             'He': 16,
             'Like': 2,
             'Why': 0,
             'Totally': 0,
             'Looks': 3,
             'Instead-': 0})
```

but much longer.

Comment: The keys you are using to put things in your dict are `line[0]`.  That doesn't seem right. - also, I think you want -= and *= in a few places where you have - and * respectively. - I don't see tuples though.  I think you mean something else.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "summarizing by line" . . . can you give us an example of what you want?  Also, show your input "doc".

Comment: What do you mean by "getting tuples"?  There are no tuples in the code and output you posted.  Also, note that the statement `value[line[0]] - 1` doesn't do anything - you compute a value, then throw it away.  You need `-=` instead (and `*=` for the next two cases).

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to do.  What do you want the keys in the resulting dictionary to be?

Comment: They are dictionary pairs not tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited to include value by lines that I missed until I saw the other post. I thought his understanding was a little better, but I had to split the line by spaces to properly get to the words vs iterating the characters.

```
def value_eval():
    value = 0
    line_values = defaultdict(int)
    with open('doc.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    for lineNumber, line in enumerate(lines):
            words = line.split()
            for word in words:
                if word in positive:
                    print(line)
                    value += 1
                if word in negative:
                    value -= 1
                if word in intensifiers:
                    value *= 1.25
                if word in shifters:
                    value *= -1.25
                line_values[lineNumber] = value
    return line_values
```

defaultdict(int) is going to create a dictionary where the value is an integer for each time the key occurs.

`value[line[0]] += 1` is adding the first word of each line into your dictionary as the key and the incremented assignment portion as the value to that key.

I got to playing around...it my math is correct...kind of tired, you can add in the following to get a page value

```
def get_avg_page_value(doc_values, total_lines, pages ):
    values = 0
    for x in range(total_lines):
        values += doc_values[x]
    print("average: {}".format(values/pages))

doc_values = value_eval()
lines_per_page = 20
total_lines = len(doc_values.values())
pages = int(total_lines/lines_per_page)
get_avg_page_value(doc_values, total_lines, pages)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want for the keys in your resulting dictionary, but assuming you want line numbers, I think this is what you might be thinking:

```
def value_eval(doc):
    value = defaultdict(int)
    for lineNumber, line in enumerate(doc):
        value = 0
        for word in line:
            if word in positive:
                value += 1
            if word in negative:
                value -= 1
            if word in intensifiers:
                value *= 1.25
            if word in shifters:
                value *= -1.25
        value[lineNumber] = value
    return value
```

If you want the keys in your result to be something other than line numbers, then you just need to do something else on the 2nd to last line.

I wonder what your input is.  For this to work, `doc` has to be some kind of iterable (lines) where each value inside it is also an iterable (words).  If `doc` were, for example, an input file handle, this wouldn't work.